# Select a button by its value and click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can I select a button based on its value and click on it (in Javascript)?

I already found it in JQuery:

```
$('input [type = button] [value = my task]');
```

My HTML Code for the Button is :

```
<button type="submit" value="My Task" id="button5b9f66b97cf47" class="green ">
<div class="button-container addHoverClick">
    <div class="button-background">
        <div class="buttonStart">
            <div class="buttonEnd">
                <div class="buttonMiddle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-content">Lancer le pillage</div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="button5b9f66b97cf47_script">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('button#button5b9f66b97cf47').click(function () {
            jQuery(window).trigger('buttonClicked', [this, {"type":"submit","value":"My Task","name":"","id":"button5b9f66b97cf47","class":"green ","title":"","confirm":"","onclick":""}]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**What is the equivalent** in JS and how may i click on it 
(probably like this: `buttonSelected.click();` ) .

*And how do i run the javascript of the button clicked ?*

Comment: jQuery has a method that clicks for you which you already used. Doesn't that work? `buttonSelected.click()`

Comment: use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select it. Then click()

Your HTML has a button and not an input element so I changed the selector to match the HTML.

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button[value="my task"]');
button.click();
```

```html
<button type="submit" value="my task" id="button5b9f54e9ec4ad" class="green " onclick="alert('clicked')">
    <div class="button-container addHoverClick">
        <div class="button-background">
            <div class="buttonStart">
                <div class="buttonEnd">
                    <div class="buttonMiddle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-content">Launch</div>
    </div>
</button>
```

Otherwise, use this selector:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="button"][value="my task"]')
```

Note that if you have multiple buttons with the same value you'll need to use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and you'll get a list of all the buttons.
Then you can loop over them and `click()` them all.

### Edit - new snippet after question edit

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('button#button5b9f66b97cf47').click(function() {alert('success')});
  document.querySelector('button[value="My Task"]').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" value="My Task" id="button5b9f66b97cf47" class="green ">
<div class="button-container addHoverClick">
    <div class="button-background">
        <div class="buttonStart">
            <div class="buttonEnd">
                <div class="buttonMiddle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-content">Lancer le pillage</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you, i updated my post can you please tell me why when i click on the buttton it don't run the button's javascript, and how can i do to make this work ?

Comment: From what I understand, you're trying to trigger a custom event "buttonClicked" on the window object. But without a handler for that custom event, nothing will happen. Can you explain what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I am building an extension for a website and i wouldlike my extension to click on the button with the value "My Task" then it run the javascript of the button (the javascript on the website).

Comment: If there is an event handler for the click event of the button it will execute it. The click event that you use in your example is this: `function () {
            jQuery(window).trigger('buttonClicked', [this,{...}]);
        });` which triggers the custom event 'buttonClicked' with all the parameters. Can try binding something simple first, like `alert('test')` and see that the code runs when you trigger the click?

Comment: Check my latest edit. I used the way you bind to the click event and the code is executing. Maybe you have a problem with the code that you bind to the click event or you try to trigger the click before you bind the handler.

Comment: The Button Selection seems not working. ( It display NULL) when i do (             
 `alert(document.querySelector('input[type="button"][value="my task"]'));`
)

Comment: That's because the value of the button is "**M**y **T**ask" and not "**m**y **t**ask" (notice the capital letters). Try `alert(document.querySelector('input[type="button"][value="My Task"]'));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180188/discussion-between-dorian-grn-and-oram).

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type = button][value=something]");
```

note that querySelectorAll returns array so to get the element you should use indexing to index the first element of the returned array and then to click:

```
  elements[0].click()
```

and to add a event listener u can do:

```
  elements[0].addEventListener('click', function(event){
     event.preventDefault()
      //do anything after button is clicked
  })
```

and don't forget to add onclick attribute to your button element in html to call the equivalent function in  your javascript code with event object

Comment: Hi thank you, i updated my post can you please tell me why when i click on the buttton it don't run the button's javascript, and how can i do to make this work ?

Comment: I have updated the answer for you, tell me if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScripts `querySelector` in similiar manner works in this case

```
document.querySelector('input[type="button"][value="my task" i]')
```

**EDIT**

You might save your selection in variable and attach `eventListener` to it. This would work as you desire.

Notice `event.preventDefault()` -function, if this would be part of form it would example prevent default from send action and you should trigger sending form manually. `event`-variable itselfs contains object about your `click`-event

```
var button = document.querySelector('input[type="button"][value="my task" i]')

button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault() // Example if you want to prevent button default behaviour
  // RUN YOUR CODE =>
  console.log(123)
})
```

Comment: The button selection seems not working. I tried alert(button); and it display "NULL" is that normal ?

Comment: Sorry, I had typoed `[value="my task"]` -attr of selection. Try now again.

Comment: @DorianGrn seems like in your example you have written "My Task" so most likely this is because case sensitivity. Just change value to match your element. Here's a dummy CodeSandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/4j97865pp9

Comment: i did but it don't work to. I really don't understand.

Comment: Did you check example code on CodeSandbox? You can achieve incasesensitive css selection with `[value="my task" i]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not recommended this way because of excess your coding but as you mentioned, below are the equivalent way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectedbuttonValue = "2"; //change value here to find that button

  var buttonList = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")
  for (i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
    var currentButtonValue = buttonList[i];
    if (selectedbuttonValue == currentButtonValue.value) {
      currentButtonValue.click();
    }
  }

});

function callMe(valuee) {
  alert(valuee);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="1" onclick="callMe(1)" />
<input type="button" class="btn" value="2" onclick="callMe(2)" />
<input type="button" class="btn" value="3" onclick="callMe(3)" />
```